# Joining 3 SQL tables without foreign keys relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join 3 SQL tables into one. 2 of them are linked by a foreign key but the 3rd isn't.

The 3 tables schemes are:

> PaysSociete

[image: PaysSociete]

> Employe

[image: Employe]

> Ligne

[image: Ligne]

I want to join the 3 of them into a unique table called **User** with the following columns:

- `Pays`: PaysSociete.LibellePaysSociete
- `Societe`: Employe.SOCIETE
- `Utilisateur`: Ligne.UtilisateurLigne
- `Matricule`: Employe.Matricule
- `NumLigne`: Ligne.Numero
- `EmpMetier`: Employe.SectionIris

In the table `Ligne`, the column `CodeSociete` corresponds to the `id`column in the table `PaysSociete` (as a foreign key)

The column `Societe` of the table `Employe` corresponds to the `CodePaysSociete` column in `PaysSociete` (but it's not a foreign key because it isn't unique)

Here is my request:

```
select
case
when p.PaysSocieteId=1 then 'CountryCode1'
when p.PaysSocieteId=2 then 'CountryCode2'
when p.PaysSocieteId=3 then 'CountryCode3'
end Pays,

p.CodePaysSociete Societe,
l.UtilisateurLigne Utilisateur,
e.Matricule Matricule,
l.Numero NumLigne,
e.SectionIris EmpMetier

from Ligne as l 
join PaysSociete as p on l.CodeSociete=CONVERT(varchar(10), p.PaysSocieteId)
join Employe as e on e.Societe = p.CodePaysSociete
```

But i'm getting a bad result with duplicated `User.Matricule` and `User.EmpMetier` columns.

How can I fix it?

Please help!!!

Comment: Sample data and desired result would help.  I don't understand why a simple `JOIN` query wouldn't do what you want.

Comment: What makes you think you need a foreign key relationship to join tables?   Did you get some error when you tried?   what was the error?

Answer (score 4):

You can join tables on any column that corresponds to an other column. A foreign key is not necessary for a join.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Ligne
  JOIN PaysSociete ON Ligne.CodeSociete = CONVERT(varchar(10), PaysSociete.id)
  JOIN Employe ON Employe.Societe = PaysSociete.CodePaysSociete
```

Comment: You'd need to cast the int as a varchar for the types to play nice.

Comment: Just to let you know, I edited your answer to reflect this.  Next time be sure to update your answer if something should need a change. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The column `ReferentielId` of **`Ligne`** handled datas from column `EmployeId` of **`Employe`**.

A simple junction works.

Sorry for the trouble.